# Applications of Cesaro's lemma to probability theory

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, cesaro-summable

I am currently trying to collect applications of Cesaro's lemma to various fields.

I suspect that there are (elementary) applications of this lemma to probability theory but couldn't find any.

Suggestions and references would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- A consequence of Cesàro's lemma is [Kronecker's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma), which can be used to prove laws of large numbers.
- I can think of two related (negative) results:

1. A sequence of i.i.d. random variables cannot converge almost surely, unless it is a deterministic sequence.
2. If a sequence of random variables converges in probability, then it is not necessary true for its Cesàro mean.